# Where should I declare my "count" vaiable correctly?

Tags: java, swing, button

I was wondering where should I place my countA correctly, because I want a count to be added to every button that is made. The 'count' variable in the beginning is for making the new button, the 'countA' is the count I'm trying to declare, but it doesn't compile. Here is a snippet of my code: Again my question is, where should I declare the **countA** variable so that it creates a new count every time for my button. Thanks!

```
                public static int count = 0;

                class ClickListener implements ActionListener
                {                                   
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                    {                                                        
                        count++;            
                        if (count % 2 != 0)    
                        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                            str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the name of the new Button?"); 
                            JButton b = new JButton(str);
                            b18.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));

                            int countA = 0;

                            b.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                            b.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                            b.setOpaque(true);
                            b.setFocusable(false);

                            add(b18);

                            class ClickListenerEighteen implements ActionListener
                            {

                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                                {                                                                                                                         
                                    countA++;

                                    if (countA % 2 != 0)
                                    {

                                        System.out.println("This new button was clicked")                                                                                       
                                    }                                      
                                    else 
                                    {                                            
                                        System.out.println("This button was clicked so that I know");                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                    }                                        
                                }                                   
                            }
                            ActionListener bClicked = new ClickListener();
                            b.addActionListener(bClicked);
                        }
                    } 
                }
```

Comment: `countA` should be declared based on the scope you want to use it I would suggest that been declared within the context of the `ActionListener`'s `actionPeformed` method is a bad idea and maybe make it an instance field of the `ActionListener` instead

Comment: I'd also be worried about the compounding nature of your code, it's hard to read and follow the logic, it might be better to generate inner classes which are dedicated to the task you are trying to accomplish

Comment: how would I make it an instance field of the ActionListener?

Comment: This is part of my inner class, I'm just posting a snippet of my code

Comment: I'd still be worried about the use of anonymous class like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how would I make it an instance field of the ActionListener?

Like you would for any other class...

```
class ClickListener implements ActionListener
{       
    protected int countA;                            
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {                                                        
        count++;
```

Comment: this compiled for me, but what does the protected mean?

Comment: `protected` means that anyone within the same package can access the field (from an instance of the class) (as well as subclasses), see [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for more details. In this case, it might not make much difference

Comment: Do I need to set countA to 0? Or is it default for 0?

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I've been working on this for such a long time, and it worked!